# Type cast in cocoa for fix warnings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, casting

I have next situation:

Method:

```
-(void) myMethod:(id)inValue
{
     long a = [inValue longValue];
}
```

Compiler shows me a warning that -longValue - is multiplied:

```
multiple methods named '-longValue' found
```

What can I do to resolve this warning without change method name?

Thank!

Comment: What kind of object are you expecting, e.g. `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 3):

Strongly type your method's argument to tell the compiler which variant of the `-longValue` message you want to use, e.g.:

```
-(void) myMethod:(NSNumber *)inValue
{
     long a = [inValue longValue];
}
```

If you want to accept multiple types that respond to `-longValue` (say, `NSNumber` and `NSString`) then you'll have to go back to using `id` and you'll see the warning. You see, something in your (yes, your, not Apple's) class hierarchy has bunged up and used a different signature for `-longValue`, so the compiler has no way of knowing which one you want to use. `id` tells it "this is an object" but it provides no explicit information that the compiler can use to resolve its conundrum.

Is there a particular reason why you're passing an `id` instead of a strongly-typed object?

Comment: id - because function works with different objects with similar interface.

Comment: Well, one or more of those classes has an interface that defines `-longValue` as returning something other than `long`. Better find it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm understood where from this warning - it completely right. If I were compiler developer - I were make possible something like this:

```
id a = [[[inValue class] alloc]] init];
```

for type cast; and after this may be:

```
a = inValue

[a longValue];
```

for resolve this warning.

But I'm not.) 
And I'm only study programming for Mac.  So i just asking - it possible or not.